# Android sdk is there a maximum size for images placed in the drawable directory?

Tags: android, image, drawable

I am placing a 3mb image in the drawable folder but it causes a error in the "gen" folder with "R". If I put a smaller image it's ok. Does anyone know if there is a size restriction with the drawable folder?

Comment: The error is "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Are the names of the files in proper format. Use only small letters and underscore

Comment: I used "import" selecting the "drawable" folder to add the image

Comment: Thanks that was it the file name had all numbers